# TextFormField not resetting when exiting page

Tags: flutter

I made the `TextFormField` Widget to be able to use it wherever needed. The codes are as follows;

```
  Widget TextFormFieldWidget(
    TextEditingController controller,
    Icon icon,
    String hintText,
    bool obscureText,
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
              primary: Colors.red,
            ),
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: obscureText,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          prefixIcon: icon,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xFFCB3126),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm having a problem. Here's the problem: I'm making a registration page. When the user exits the page and enters back, the values ​​entered in the `TextFormField` are not reset. For example, let me give an example that the user gives up after entering their e-mail address. When you leave the page and enter back, the e-mail address is not deleted.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the text controllers value when you exit the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dispose the controller
2. Clear the Conroler.

   ```
   ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      controller.clear();

                    }, 
                    child: Text("Send")
                   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use one (a shared) TextController an the one TextController gets passed in to each TextFormFieldWidget, the the single controller will have a single state.

Thus, it keeps its value when getting attached to a new TextFormFieldWidget.

**Please use different TextEditingController for different fields.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue with creating a function to return a `Widget` is such. If you're making a custom widget for your app, let's say reusable custom text field, It is suggested to be made into a separate `StatefulWidget`.

When you use stateful widget, you make a new instance of the same widget as per needed.
Use the below mentioned code to create the same for yours.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class CustomTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextFormField(
      {required this.icon,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.obscureText,
      super.key});

  final Icon icon;
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;

  @override
  State<CustomTextFormField> createState() => _CustomTextFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFormFieldState extends State<CustomTextFormField> {
  late TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: ThemeData().colorScheme.copyWith(
              primary: Colors.red,
            ),
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: widget.obscureText,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          prefixIcon: widget.icon,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              color: Color(0xFFCB3126),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```